# How to see the variable's value while debugging in sql server

Tags: sql-server

[image: I can set the debugging on sql-server queries. But what, I need to see the value while debugging. So, that's my question how to see the variable's value while the debugging like C# debugging control (Shift+F9) keys]

I can set the debugging on sql-server queries. But what, I need to see the value while debugging. So, that's my question how to see the variable's value while the debugging like C# debugging control (Shift+F9) keys

Answer (score 0):

use print;

```
print @Variable
```

....

Comment: Ok, but I want to see the '@variable<5' 's value. Definitely it returns boolean value. But how to see it in sql

Answer (score 0):

`Shift +  F9` also works here for Quick Watch, Then type your variable in Watch window.

Comment: Already i tried it but I want to see the '@variable<5' 's value. Can I check that in Watch Window?

Comment: You can easily see the value of @variable and decide yourself whether @variable<5 is true or false.